# How to set the focus to an input field that didn't pass the validation

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 1.1 web application with a form with some input fields that are validated. when the user submits the form and the submitted input doesn't pass the validation, i'd like that the focus is set automatically to the (first) input field that didn't pass the validation.

Is there a way to do it in ASP.NET Core?

in webforms there were various server controls for validation (e.g. the `RequiredFieldValidator`) that referred to an input field and had a property named `SetFocusOnError` that allowed this function. so i was wondering if there is something similar for ASP.NET Core...

Comment: Can you post some code of how you are building UI and validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core you have to generate the required HTML and javascript to do this.
You have to add a [Tag Helper](https://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/adding-a-bootstrap-css-class-for-validation-failure-in-asp-net-core) to add a validation class

```
<div class="editor-field @Html.AddValidationClass("Email", "has-error")">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
</div>
```

and then you could use a jQuery class selector:

```
$(function() {
    $('.has-error :input').focus();
});
```

Comment: the jquery-code in your answer was the part that i was missing.
just a remark: how would you extend your code to support also other controls like dropdownlists, checkboxes, radiobuttons etc?

is it enough to remove the :input specification so that the focus will apply to all items that have the class "has-error"?

Comment: Yes,we can remove the input.You may also get errors in multiple controls so you can  get focus on something like the first one  `$('.has-error').first().focus();`